# How to auto-wrap if total html or component properties >= n?

Tags: visual-studio-code

As I understand with the default settings in vscode. The properties below will only auto-wrap when it reaches to the maxiumum `wordWrapColumn`. (See below)

```
<h1 className="sample" height="20" width="30" color="20" size="200" />

// auto separated
<h1
    className="sample"
    height="20"
    width="30"
    color="blue"
    size="200"
/>
```

---

I wanna ask if its possible to change this behavior? Instead of basing to `wordWrapColumn`, we check the total properties of an element / component.
We auto-newline when it reaches to the specified total props.

```
totalHtmlProps = 3

## case 1
<h1 className="sample" height="20" />


## case 2
<h1
    className="sample"
    height="20"
    color="blue"
/>
```

a quick update: i'm also using prettier with this.